# Ubuntu Server 23.10 on Raspberry Pi 5 fails to register on home router

Tags: ubuntu, server, pi-5

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 23.10 via Raspberry Pi Imager. I used custom settings to set a hostname, ssh username and password, etc. I did not include a WiFi SSID and password. When connected to my home network it doesn't show up on the network. I have 5 Raspberry Pi 3s that are showing up no problem using an Ubuntu Server 23.10 through the Imager. Anything I need to try or do differently. Should I revert to the old way of adding the ssh file at the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the imager does not correctly configure any OS except Raspberry Pi OS.

Last time I used Ubuntu server it used yaml to setup systemd-networkd but did not setup WiFi although this may have changed.

I recommend you do a fresh install and configure manually.

Comment: I was able to install Ubuntu Server 23.10 to a Raspberry Pi 3 last week using Imager. The SSH worked out of the box with the custom settings.

Answer (score 0):

There was not enough power getting to the board. The ethernet port was not powered correctly.